# Mathematics word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this an algebraic equation. Here it is.

> Randy was counting mangoes in a basket. After counting 2/5 of the
>   mangoes, his cellphone rang and he answered it. Then, he continued to
>   count. After counting 20 more, he still had 1/2 of the mangoes to
>   count. How many mangoes were there in the basket.

Effort: $N$ is the number of mangoes in the basket. Then:
$$
(2/5) N + 20
$$

Any links to your answer will be highly appreciated.
To be honest I need a detailed answer here so if you can type down your solution kindly do so.

Sorry to sound a bit demanding but I know internet can help me.

Thank You!

Comment: This seems straightforward.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MlYly2qMNhUImv7SG4DNT_t6swZQ54sY/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Why did you show your effort in the comments instead of in the question right after Jose Carlos Santos asked you not to do so?  Also, why did you put your response in an image instead of as text?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Luvsip5NprIAI4NMWedmfWQYYxLi8cz6/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Close. Shift the "=" one to the left.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack exchange forgive me. I didn't mean to violate your rules here if you can guide me please do so I am really sorry.

Comment: Please don't put "mathematics" in the title. This is a mathematics site; all the questions are about mathematics. The title should describe the question as succinctly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The question says "After counting 2/5 of the mangoes, his cellphone rang and he answered it. Then, he continued to count. After counting 20 more, he still had 1/2 of the mangoes to count". This means that 2/5 of mangoes plus 20 mangoes is equal to half the mangoes (because if he has 1/2 mangoes left to count he has counted 1/2 mangoes). This can be expressed as 
2/5x + 20 = 1/2x which is 4/10x+20=5/10x (finding a common denominator and expressing the amount of mangoes as a variable, x). As a result, 1/10x = 20. x = 200.

We can check our answer by plugging in 200 to the original equation, 
2/5(200)+20=1/2(200) which can be simplified to 80+20=100, since 80+20 does equal 100 we can verify that **There were 200 mangoes in the basket**

Comment: I know that it says that I should not post thanks here and I should not put link but kindly take time Sir/Ma'am to check my own understanding I also ask in other sites. But I would like to show you how I answer it also. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HlzyMq-pXO7hjhALYTxw4Mon0ugMGgr5/view?usp=drivesdk I am really grateful to your answer. Spare me with my kind of comment. Thanks really.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 20 mangoes to 40 percent of the mangoes equal half the number of mangoes: 
$\frac{2}{5}N + 20 = \frac{1}{2}N$

Comment: Here you could get away with decimal fractions, as you probably can invert $0.1$ without pocket calculator or Wolfram Alpha on your smart device. In general fractions are more suited for calculations involving algebraic transformation steps.

Comment: @mvw Some people prefer using fractions. Why does it matter?

Comment: @Sambo the original comments were deleted. I used decimals first, and mvw suggested I change to fractions. I asked why, above is their response :)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I misinterpreted the comment